# How to change background color in jspdf

Tags: jspdf

I try to export image to PDF , But black background is showing around the image in PDF file. How can I remove this black background ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to export image to PDF as png it works for me .

```
var canvas = plot.getCanvas();
var src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
doc.addImage(src, 'PNG', 10, 20, 280, 150);
```

Please review full demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8tLt9yof/10/) working well in Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to PDF viewer cannot be done in the cloud since the viewers are user application extensions to their browser so every browser can be set different by the client.

[image]

There seems to be a lack of knowledge that the web is in effect a transfer of data where the browser is responsible for securely requesting, accepting and editing the incoming into the display, thus a server can only advise not control such incoming data. Any attempt to control the user such as adverts, or other non-requested cajoling should ideally be blocked.

[image]

for more examples of colouring blackground's see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74228850/10802527