# How can I enable dark mode when viewing a pdf file in firefox

Tags: pdf, firefox, darkmode

I have enabled the dark mode in Firefox version 76.0 as well as installed the dark reader extension. The extension allows web pages to go dark. These changes do not affect any PDFs that have been opened in Firefox.

Comment: I just normally open F12 while reading any PDF and enter the below command in console.: `viewer.style = 'filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) sepia(1)'`

Comment: it doesn't work for me; it reports an error

Comment: Is it possible to have separate bookmarks for solarized dark and solarized light?

Comment: @Porcupine Yes, but you cannot possibly use CSS filters to accurately recreate the Solarized colorscheme. You may want to try out [_doqment_](https://github.com/shivaprsd/doqment) (Disclaimer: I am the author).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Create a bookmarklet - a bookmark with the following in the location/address/URL field:

```js
javascript:(function(){var el = typeof viewer !== 'undefined' ? viewer : document.body; el.style.filter = 'grayscale(1) invert(1) sepia(1) contrast(75%)';})()
```

Then, click on this bookmark after you open a PDF in Firefox.

Comment: Please add steps like how to achieve the outcome(As suggestion queue is full, adding my view of how to apply this trick, as follows),
1. Open the file (which is saved locally or from a downloadable link) in the browser 2. Then, Click on the bookmark (That will update the style of the document to dark related colors)

Comment: Or you can just click F-12, switch to "Console" Tab and paste the script

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: viewer is not defined`

Comment: For me, i found that `grayscale(1)` and `sepia(1)` were too harsh - instead i just kept `'filter:  invert(1) contrast(50%)'` which just inverts the blacks and whites and adds a contrast of 50% so you get a nice grey backdrop against a white-ish text.

Comment: In Firefox 109.0.1 (64 bit) on Linux Mint, the location/address field will be called the URL field. It doesn't matter what you set the location field (bookmark folder) to or what you set the name to.

Comment: @EnthusiastiC Try putting this code in the location or address field instead: `javascript:(function(){var el = typeof viewer !== 'undefined' ? viewer : document.body; el.style = 'filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) sepia(1) contrast(75%)';})()` It'll work on all pages.

Comment: Is it possible to have separate bookmarks for solarized dark and solarized light?

Comment: If you like darker, change `contrast(75%)` to `contrast(80%)` or higher

Comment: Does anyone know how to set the pdf background to a specific color in hex value, e.g., #FBF0D9 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can see it in https://pncnmnp.github.io/blogs/firefox-dark-mode.html

1. Open Firefox and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show the top menu, then click on Help → More Troubleshooting Information *(Troubleshooting Information on older versions of Firefox)*.
2. Click the Open Folder button beside the Profile Folder entry.
3. Create a folder named `chrome` in the directory that opens.
4. In the `chrome` folder, create a CSS file with the name `userContent.css`
5. Open the `userContent.css` file and insert:

   ```css
   #viewerContainer > #viewer > .page > .canvasWrapper > canvas {
      filter: grayscale(100%);
      filter: invert(100%);
   }
   ```
6. On Firefox's URL bar, type `about:config`.
7. Search for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` and set it to `true`.
8. Restart Firefox and fire up a PDF file to see the change!

Comment: To redo it, set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` back to `false`.

Answer (score 9):

Simple bookmarklet toggler
Just run snippet and drag link to Bookmarks Toolbar

```html
<a href="javascript:(function(v) {v.style = v.classList.contains('dm')?'':'filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) sepia(1) contrast(75%)';v.classList.toggle('dm');})(viewer)">PDF darkmode toggler</a>
```

Unminified:

```
(
    function() {
        if (viewer.classList.contains("dm")) viewer.style = "";
        else viewer.style = "filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) sepia(1) contrast(75%)'";
        viewer.classList.toggle("dm");
    }
)()
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how to make the full page dark

## Tutorial

1. Add a new Bookmark
2. Copy the following snippet: `javascript:(function(){document.body.parentElement.style = 'filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) contrast(0.8)';})()`
3. Paste it into the bookmark's address
4. Save the bookmark
5. Whenever you're on a PDF, click on the bookmark

## Explanation

This is a bookmark that executes Javascript (this is why it starts with `javascript` and not with `http` or `https`).
In the Javascript code we get the root `html` tag (`document.body.parentElement`) and change it's style `.style = 'filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) contrast(0.8)';`.

That's literally everything :)

Answer (score 0):

For those with other FireFox PDF Viewers apart from PDF.js,
[image]
it may not always be possible to run unsecured JS but the viewer may have its own inversion options .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

1. Go to this site https://www.yourjs.com/bookmarklet/
2. input this script (was mentioned above too)

```
    javascript:(function(){document.body.parentElement.style = 'filter:
        grayscale(1) invert(1) contrast(0.8)';})()
```

Open your PDF in Firefox as you normally would and it will make the pages dark.